# 14.04 accidentally upgraded - fglrx removed

Tags: 14.04, drivers, xubuntu, fglrx

Since the message about HWE has appeared in Software Update on my Xubunu 14.04 running on a Thinkpad T500, I have avoided updating. But today, I accidentally clicked the wrong button *and* typed my password, and to my great dismay, I saw it upgradeto the new X and "open" driver. Sure enough, just as when I tested 16.04, the Thinkpad now acts strangely, the cursor disappeared after sleep, and the machine feels sluggish.

Is there a way to revert this update - other than installing Xubuntu 14.04 LTS again from scratch?

When can I expect a driver that works for T500 (and for my W500 for that matter?)

(And, no offense intended, but why on earth break a LTS version with such a change? I am using LTS precisely because I wanted to avoid such problems!)